# Can I put up a fullscreen video placeholder on a website to play a video as a website intro animation instead of coding the animation manually?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to web development and have little knowledge as I've just started and wanted to try this one, thank you!

I haven't tried it as I'm searching for solutions as I still have little knowledge in basic web development.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would suggest you use the html video tag to play the video on your website.

```
<style>
  .video-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
  }
  video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    object-fit: cover;
  }
</style>

<div class="video-container">
  <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

You can modify the CSS to fit your needs.